# Monkey Patching Float Infix Operator's Produces Unexpected Results

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, arithmetic-expressions

Redefining `Float#/` appears to have no effect:

```
class Float
  def /(other)
    "magic!"
  end
 end
 puts 10.0/2.0 # => 5.0
```

But when another infix operator `Float#*` is redefined, `Float#/` suddenly takes on the new definition:

```
class Float
  def /(other)
    "magic!"
  end
  def *(other)
    "spooky"
  end
end
puts 10.0/2.0 # => "magic!"
```

I would love to hear if anybody can explain the source of this behavior and if anybody else gets the same results.

- Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]

To quickly confirm the bug, run [this script](http://chopapp.com/#5cjhcx4j).

Comment: Confirmed on Ubuntu 13.04 with Ruby 2.0.0p247. Perhaps this out to be listed as a bug? [Ruby Issue Tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/)

Comment: For me both are giving `"magic"` output... I am on `kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [i686-linux]
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ `

Comment: Got same result on Mac/MRI Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @NeilSlater what is your patch number?

Comment: I am getting the correct result in 1.8.7p367

Comment: Interestingly, this happens only for `Float`. I just tested with `Fixnum`

Comment: Interestingly, while `10.0/2.0` returns a Float, `10.0.send(:/,2.0)` returns `"magic!"`

Comment: Reported. [Ruby Issue Tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9237)

Comment: I got the same result on Linux, and since all three major platforms (Windows, Mac OS, Linux) behave the same, it looks the OS is irrelevant. I removed the OS description from the question, accordingly.

Comment: This bug is seems to be resolved in 2.1.0dev

Comment: @screenmutt No, it is not resolved. I ran it in 2.1.0dev (2013-11-23 trunk 43807), and got the same result.

Comment: @sawa I ran it in 2.1.0 dev and it ran without the bug.

Comment: @screenmutt: I was using 2.0.0p247, and confirmed bug in two separate IRB sessions (running no other code)

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Indeed. The bug was in the YARV optimization code. The optimization is not used when using `send`. I talk about a similar bug in my rubyconf talk http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2894-rubyconf2013-ruby-core-dilemmas

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune Just watched your talk. Delightful! Kudos to you (for your work and the talk) and thanks for the link. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the implementation of Ruby. A bug report has been filed [here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9237).

In the mean time, you may either switch implementations or switch versions. 1.8.7 appears to be bug free.

**EDIT**

[This bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9238) was fixed with [revision 44127](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi?revision=44127&view=revision)

Comment: What is the basis of your claim that 2.1 is bug free?

Comment: @sawa IRB was bug free in 2.1 for me, but when I ran it as a script the bug was present.

Comment: Yup :-) Cute bug! (and fixed...)